# What is the command in Minecraft to clone only one type of block in a certain area to another?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have build a circular platform out of sandstone with a radius of 50 and I wish to make it thicker without building another layer. Is there a command to clone only only sandstone in a large area one block down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filtered` parameter.

```
/clone <x> <y> <z> <x> <y> <z> <x> <y> <z> filtered sandstone
```